# Android Studio next page Button not working

Tags: java

I created a android studio button for my app and when I click on the 'Proceed' button it doesn't work. I don't get any errors it just doesn't work. When the user clicks the 'Proceed' button I want to go to the First Quiz.java.

I have looked at all other similar questions but cannot seem to find what I am doing wrong.

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.john.quiz1;

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button btn;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            startActivityFromFragment(new Intent(MainActivity.this, FirstQuiz.class));

        }

        private void startActivityFromFragment(Intent intent) {
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
// Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
// automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
// as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
//noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="160dp"
        android:text="Welcome to Road Sign Quiz"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#0000ff"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:background="#0000ff"
        android:text="proceed"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="25dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

FirstQuiz.java

```
package com.example.john.quiz1;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;

import com.example.john.quiz1.R;

public class FirstQuiz extends AppCompatActivity {
    private RadioGroup radioGroup;
    private Button nxt;
    int pos;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.quiz1);
        radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
        radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId){
                if (checkedId == R.id.radio1) {
                    setContentView(R.layout.final2);
                }
                else if (checkedId == R.id.radio2){
                    setContentView(R.layout.final2);
                }
                else if (checkedId == R.id.radio3) {
                    setContentView(R.layout.final1);
                }
                else{
                    setContentView(R.layout.final2);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `startActivityFromFragment` method should be outside of your `onClickListener()`. This method is also empty, so it's not going to do anything when you call it.

It also looks like `onCreateOptionsMenu` and `onOptionsItemSelected` is outside your `MainActivity` class.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting only startActivity(intent) and also android:clickable="true" and android:focusable="true" in your button xml.

Also I've noticed that your startActivityFromFragment() method won't do anything because you are calling an empty method, so in that method you should launch the intent.